# Find day from given date in python

Tags: python, datetime, odoo, dayofweek

Hello friends I have written two methods in python which returns the day according to the date passed to them but however the output I am getting is different in some cases.
Pasting my code below please have a look at it and suggest me corrections....

e.g. for date  "10/06/2014" (m/d/yy) one function returns output as Monday which is correct and another returns it as Sunday which is not.
I am using Odoo8 (Openerp) server's method in one case and Python's method in other.

```
def a():
    month, day, year = (int(x) for x in "10/06/2014".split('/'))
    ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    day_name = ans.strftime("%A")    # the day_name is Monday here


def b():
    dt = datetime.strptime("10/06/2014", "%m/%d/%y")
    dt = fields.Datetime.context_timestamp(self, dt)   # openerp's ORM method 
    t = dt.strftime("%A")        # the day_name is Sunday here
```

Comment: I'm surprised this code actually works because your date string and the date format don't match. Are you sure you are pasting the correct code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's because you are to the west of Greenwich, `datetime.date` is timezone-unaware, and `openerp.fields.Datetime.context_timestamp` is timezone-aware.

If your timezone is PST, for example, the timestamp `10/06/2014 0:00 UTC` becomes `10/05/2014 16:00 PST`, which is obviously Sunday.

Comment: Thank you @Andrey Sobolev it was timezone issue, got resolved now.